# generated excel file url

Tags: javascript, java, excel

There's an excel file I want to download parse in java but I can't figure out what is the URL I need to use.

The site is [here](http://www.boi.org.il/en/DataAndStatistics/Page/SeriesSearchBySubject.aspx?Level=4&sId=50)
and I would like to get the excel file of NIS/dollar representative exchange rate   of `05.1986-05.2016`.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the URL to download the excel sheet.

http://www.boi.org.il/en/DataAndStatistics/Pages/boi.ashx?Command=DownloadSeriesExcel&SeriesCode=MAT01.MA&DateStart=01/05/1986&DateEnd=31/05/2016&Level=4&Sid=50

But I need to mention to you that this question is not of relevance or use to other fellow users as this is very business specific. The thing which might interest SO users is how to get that URL. And I achieved that through Google Chrome Developer Tool. You just monitor the undergoing traffic and from there you could easily find the download URL.